# Django Foreign Key. Delete connection after one exact date

Tags: python, django

For example i have 2 models

**products.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**clients.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
      client_product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
      client_product_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now:

**Product**

`name = Chocolate`

**Client**

`name = John`

`client_product = Chocolate`

`client_product_expiry_date = 2017.12.17 (after 3 days)`

After certain days (which was set in field **`client_product_expiry_date`**)
This connection between **client** and **product** should be removed

Is there any way how to realize it?

Comment: Look for [`cron job`](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) or `Celery` which would be able to do your job.

Comment: Either delete the entry from the DB, or add a dedicated flag: `client_product_expired` = `True`/`False` and implement a `Manager` for it`

Comment: Do you want to delete the product after date passes away? is that your question @Sam

Comment: No) I want remove connection between product and client. After exact date product should not be related to client

Comment: *Connection* means an entry in the database - what you can do with it is what I proposed already. I can't think of other viable options.

Comment: Connection in the database between tables Products and Client. Just remove this connection after exact date. Nothing should go away Adelin

Comment: When django creates a connection between tables `Product` and `Client` it actually creates **another table** in which each entry represents the "connection" you mention. So, deleting an entry in **this** table means removing a connection you want removed.

Comment: Yest Something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating what I said in the comments:

When django creates a connection between tables `Product` and `Client` it actually creates another table in which each entry represents the *"connection"* you mention (`John` and `Chocolate`).

To remove the connection, you can:

a)  either delete such an entry from the database.

b) or add a dedicated flag: `client_product_expired` = `True`/`False` (ideally also implement a `Manager` for it)

To achieve the "past x time" task, you can use what [Bijoy suggested in the comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812714/django-foreign-key-delete-connection-after-one-exact-date#comment82586757_47812714) "Look for cron job or Celery which would be able to do your job"

That said, I suggest you read more about Python and Django. Questions which don't show research effort will get you plenty of downvotes around this place.